Impossible emacs installation because of postfix configuration
I have just installed latest version of Ubuntu, and tried to install emacs with sudo apt install emacs but i got the message for postfix configuration. After that i installed mail transfer agent with sudo apt install open smtpd and everything was okey.
My question is why should i had to install mail transfer agent in order to install emacs?
